# Python: Grabbing Pixel RGB

Tags: python, colors, click

This question may be a little different, since I'm pretty much a noob at programming. I've recently started playing a Pokémon game, and I thought of an idea for a cool Python program that would be able to grab a color on a certain pixel to detect if a pokémon is [shiny](http://pokemongo.wikia.com/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon) or not.

However, due to my very limited programming experience, I don't know what modules to use and how to use them.

So basically, here's what I want it to do:

1. Move the cursor to a certain pixel and click.
2. Detect the color of a certain pixel, and compare that to the desired color.
3. If it's not desirable, click a button and re-loop until it's desirable.

So, it's pretty obvious that we'll be needing a while loop, but can someone explain how to do the above three things in relatively simple terms? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking down this list into actions and searching for answers to each action.

For example, 1 is performed by the user? So we don't have to program that.

For 2, we need to determine the location of the mouse [when clicked](http://Try%20breaking%20down%20this%20list%20into%20actions%20and%20searching%20for%20answers%20to%20each%20action.%20For%20example,%201.%20is%20performed%20by%20the%20user?%20So%20we%20don't%20have%20to%20program%20that.%202.%20We%20need%20to%20determine%20the%20location%20of%20the%20mouse%20when%20clicked) and get [the color](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1119037) under it.

For 3, compare the RGB values (or whatever) to the desired values for that pokemon. This is complicated because your program needs to figure out which pokemon it is checking against. There are probably pokemon where their regular color is another's shiny. Try breaking down this into even smaller problems :)

No guarantees that these links will be perfect, just trying to show how you need to break down the problem into smaller, workable chunks which you can address either directly in code or by searching for other people who have already solved those smaller problems.

Comment: Actually, I plan to find them one at a time, so the chance of mixing the pokemon up due to pixel color isn't a problem (yet). I'm curious mainly though, is it possible to find the color of the pixel without screenshoting it?

Comment: Yes, I believe one of the links does that.